# Display content on certain pages

Tags: php, facebook

Can someone please help me to make the following code work ?

```
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_GET['categorie']) && $_GET['categorie'] === "navigatie_bar")
                        {
                        echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://alledaagsetips.nl"  data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>'
                        }
                        ?>
```

I need it to show the echo code that is a facebook comment box when the category is not navigatie_bar if people click on a link.

Comment: Use `!=` in condition instead of `===`.

Answer (score 0):

Print out your $_GET['categorie'] and see what comes out, my guess is the value is not "navigatie_bar".

If you get the same value, then try to use == and not ===

Answer (score 0):

> $_GET['categorie'] === "navigatie_bar"

is checking that the value is equal to that text (and is of the same type). Do you mean != (is not equal to)?

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull between "===" and "!=", also you missed ";" after the "echo" tag.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['categorie']) && ($_GET['categorie'] != "navigatie_bar"))
   {
      echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://alledaagsetips.nl"  data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>';
   }
?>
```